# next Image component doesn't load images

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a problem with next Image component as it doesn't seem to be loading the images. The component is set up like

```
<Image  className={styles.imgHomeBlock} 
                        src={testImg}
                        alt='Commercial' 
                        width='500' 
                        height='500'
                />
```

where testImg is imported like

```
import testImg from '../../public/google-map-fake.jpg';
```

When I bring it up it doesn't load as it is looking for the image on "localhost:3000/_next/image/google-map-fake.jpg" and that folder doesn't exist anywhere.

Serving the image in an html img works just fine. Image is placed in public folder and public folder is at the root of the project.

Putting the url directly into next Image component, passing it as a prop from its parent or putting an external url there again breaks. When for example I put an external url of an image, I still get a 404 and console indicates that it is looking for the image on "localhost:3000/_next/image/https://{image_url_here}".

Is there a way to change that "_next/image" prefix that Image component uses or else, why would the component not show the Image from the public folder directly like img tag does?

Here is the full component code:

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../../styles/T01/t01HomeBlock.module.css';

import testImg from '../../public/google-map-fake.jpg';

const T01HomeBlock = (props) => {


  return (
      <div className={styles.blockWrap}>
          <div className={styles.imgWrap}>
              <Link href={props.target}><a><p className={styles.text1}>{props.overlay}</p></a></Link>


              <Link href={props.target}><a>
            
                  <img className={styles.imgHomeBlock} src={props.bkg} alt={props.overlay}/>  //this works

                {/*
                <Image  className={styles.imgHomeBlock} 
                        src={testImg}
                        alt='Commercial' 
                        width='500' 
                        height='500'
                /> //this doesn't
                */}


            </a></Link>




        </div>
        <p className={styles.blockText}>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
   );

}

export default T01HomeBlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to import the picture not using the module, but immediately insert it into the src

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../../styles/T01/t01HomeBlock.module.css';
const T01HomeBlock = (props) => {


  return (
      <div className={styles.blockWrap}>
          <div className={styles.imgWrap}>
              <Link href={props.target}><a><p className={styles.text1}>{props.overlay}</p></a></Link>


              <Link href={props.target}><a>
            
                  <img className={styles.imgHomeBlock} src={props.bkg} alt={props.overlay}/>  //this works

                {/*
                <Image  className={styles.imgHomeBlock} 
                        src='/google-map-fake.jpg'
                        alt='Commercial' 
                        width='500' 
                        height='500'
                /> //this doesn't
                */}


            </a></Link>




        </div>
        <p className={styles.blockText}>{props.text}</p>
    </div>
   );

}

export default T01HomeBlock;
```

P.S Please note that there are no public on the way, this is how it should be

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, it is still adding _next/image in the path and getting a 404